# Wpf ViewList, how to set check box = isChecked to true, when a row is selected?

Tags: wpf

I could use some advice to set checkBox to isChecked = true when you select a row as a user. Have created a Listview, that has some GridViewColumns. One of these Columns has a checkBox inside. It look like this image:

[image: Image of my viewList]

The user can set the selected by clicking inside the CheckBox and thats okay. What I also want is that when the user select a row, like the blue one, the checkBox should be selected (Selected when blue, and unselected if you unselect it ofc)

In my Customer Model, I have one property which uses the INotifyPropertyChanged event.

```
// Room Selected property.
    public bool Selected
    {
        get
        {
            return isChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
        }
    }
```

I'm using this property to see what the user has selected when clicking further in my application.

Can you do something smart, so I still keep the property to the CustomerModel?

**ListView code**

```
<ListView Height="250" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList}" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Multiple" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView >
                            <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="Auto">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" TextAlignment="Center" Width="40"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="First name" Width="130"/>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" Header="Last name" Width="130"/>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PhoneNumber}" Header="Phone" Width="130"/>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email}" Header="Email" Width="250"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Selected" Width="Auto">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Selected}"></CheckBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Also the CustomerLits which is loaded inside the ListView is of type ObservableCollection.

Good day.

Update:

Have tried to create the start of a command.

```
SelectedChangeCommand = new RelayCommand(SelectedChangedCommand_DoWork, () => true);

// Selectionchanged Command
    void SelectedChangedCommand_DoWork(object obj)
    {

    }
```

Now I'm not so sure what to do..

Comment: You could add a selectionchanged event handler that sets the selecteditem's Selected property to true

Comment: Can you do that in XAML? I'm using Mvvm pattern, so don't want any code in the code behind.

Comment: I think you can do it with a command in that case, or add a property in your viewmodel that keeps track of the selecteditem or index and when the setter gets called updated the appropriate customer object

Comment: I think another viable option is to have a xaml trigger that sets your selection property to true when an item's isselected property(from Listviewitem) is set to true

Comment: Why did he delete his answer before? Was a quite good answer and helped me alot..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all in the XAML.

Set the IsChecked of the checkbox property binded to the listview selectedItem with a converter. If selectedItem is null return false otherwise return true.

You will end up with something like this:

```
    <ListView Height="250" Name="myListView" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList}" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Multiple" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

          ....

    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=myListView, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}"></CheckBox>
```

Give it a try :)